# Combining the arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following data arrays (a, b and c).

```
let a = [a1, a2, a3];
let b = [b1, b2, b3];
let c = [c1, c2, c3];
```

But I need the data as in array d. Is it possible to get the array d by combining a, b and c in javascript? Is there any simple method that achieves it or I've to iterate each array and conditionlly add them?

```
let d = [
         {x: a1, y: b1, z: c1}, 
         {x: a2, y: b2, z: c2}, 
         {x: a3, y: b3, z: c3}
        ]
```

Comment: The expected output is wrong.An object must have key & value

Comment: Do you mean `[[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3]]`?

Comment: @Barmar Can we get [
         {a1, b1, c1}, 
         {a2, b2, c2}, 
         {a3, b3, c3}
        ] ??

Comment: @brk Is this output alright? [{a: a1, b: b1, c: c1}, {a: a2, b: b2, c: c2}, {a: a3, b: b3, c: c3}]

Comment: Please edit the question to show that desired result. And show your attempted code, we don't write the code for you, we help you fix it.

Comment: I've undone the duplicate question, since you don't want nested arrays, but you should be able to get ideas from that question to help you write your solution.

Comment: thankyou @Barmar I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, In your case you are accessing elements of multiple arrays at a specific index position in each iteration. I can't think of any shortcut to handle this. You might need to go the iterative way. Below code could help.

```js
a = ["a1","a2","a3"]
b= ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
c= ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
// Input array
f = [a, b, c];
const length = f.length;
d = Array.from({length}).map((_val, index1) => {
    return Array.from({length}).reduce((acc, _val, index2) => {
        acc[f[index2][index1]] = f[index2][index1];
        return acc;
    }, {})
});
console.log(d);
```